# Weird execution of String method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public static String j_delete_char(String s, int index) {
    if (index >= s.length()) {
        return s;
    }

    char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
    char[] ret_s_array = new char[s.length() - 1];

    for (int i = index; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
        s_array[i] = s_array[i + 1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
        ret_s_array[i] = s_array[i];
    }

    return Arrays.toString(ret_s_array);
}

public static String j_delete_all_chars(String s, char to_del) {
    char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
    int to_del_cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s_array[i] == to_del) {
            to_del_cnt += 1;
        }
    }

    String[] ds = new String[to_del_cnt + 1];
    ds[0] = s;

    for (int StringIndex = 0; StringIndex < to_del_cnt; StringIndex++) {
        char[] ds_char_array = ds[StringIndex].toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        boolean found_to_del = false;
        while (!found_to_del) {
            if (ds_char_array[i] == to_del) {
                ds[StringIndex + 1] = j_delete_char(ds[StringIndex], i);
                found_to_del = true;
            }
            i++;
        }

    }
    return Arrays.toString(ds[to_del_cnt].toCharArray());
}
```

So `public static String j_delete_char(String s, int index)` returns string without char with index index

```
index = 3 
Input: abcdef
Output: [a, b, c, e, f]
```

And `public static String j_delete_all_chars(String s, char to_del)` returns string without all chars = to_del

I expected this method to work like this

```
to_del = '2'
Input: abcdef22abcd
Output: [a, b, c, d, e, f, a, b, c, d]
```

But I get this and I don't know what's wrong

```
[[, [, ,,  , a, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , b, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , c, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , d, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , e, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , f, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , a, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , b, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , c, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , d, ,,  , ], ]]
```

I'm new to Java, appreciate any help

Comment: This: `String[] ds = new String[to_del_cnt + 1];` does not create a string but an array of strings.  I think you're confused how string creation works.  Look at the String constructors instead: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(char%5B%5D)

Comment: Also is there a reason you don't use StringBuilder?  If you are new this could be an assignment but otherwise not re-implementing existing code is the right way to go. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt(int)

Comment: You seem new to programming in general, not just Java.  Please take a look at "hand execution."  Executing your code yourself, not relying on the computer, is imo the best way to learn how to read and write code: https://www.programming4beginners.com/tutorial/chapter04/execution-by-hand

Comment: I hesitate to suggest *regular expressions* but it's hard to beat the clarity of `return s.replaceAll(String.valueOf(to_del), "");`

Comment: yeah, it's how it should be, for every found to_del char this method creates new string, that's why I need array of strings

Comment: purpose of coding my own methods is practice, I need to improve my understanding of how strings work

Comment: It doesn't make sense to create an *addtional* container like `char[]` which is not really mutable if your objective is to mutate a string. If you want to do your 'own' string mutation, then use a mutable class like `StringBuilder` Since you're new to Java, we don't use underscores except in [places like constants](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)

Comment: `for every found to_del char this method creates new string, that's why I need array` You shouldn't do this however.  At most, you create a new string but then replace the old string, progressively creating the final string.  For a `char[]`, those are mutable, so you do NOT need to create a new one each iteration.  Just modify the one `char[]` in place.

Comment: *char to_del* You need to know, also, this is not only not future-proof, but not even present-proof. The space occupied by the world's characters has now expanded to break the bounds of `char`. We now talk of *codepoints*, which are represented by `int`. If you want to simplify this complication then you can make the search 'character' of type `String`

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, there are built-in ways to do this.  But your method is rather confusing and has a lot of unnecessary code. But here are some suggestions.

**Your `j_delete_char` method has problems.**

The idea is simple.

- create a new array one less that the original, since you will be deleting one character.
- then copy characters except the one at `index` to the new array.

```
public static String j_delete_char(String s, int index) {
    if (index >= s.length()) {
        return s;
    }
```

first, copy all the chars from 0 to index-1

```
   for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {  
      ret_s_array[i] = s_array[i];
   }
```

then copy all the characters from the index to destination, starting with the first character beyond the index.

```
   for (int i = index; i < ret_s_array.length; i++) {
      ret_s_array[i] = s_array[i+1];
   }

   return Arrays.toString(ret_s_array);
}
```

**Problems with the `j_delete_all_chars` method**

Your first part of the `j_delete_all_chars` finds out many to be deleted.  This can be used to create a proper length `result array` of characters. This is fine.  But your second loop is incorrect.  And you are creating an array of Strings based on the delete count which doesn't make sense.

```
char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
int to_del_cnt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s_array[i] == to_del) {
        to_del_cnt += 1; // in java you can also do `to_del_cnt++`
    }
}
```

So now create the result array.  Original length minus the number to be deleted.

```
char [] result = new char[s.length() - to_del_cnt];
```

Now just iterate over the existing string of characters and if the `currentChar` does **not** equal the one to be deleted, add it to the `result array` and `increment the index`.

```
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char currentChar = s.charAt(i);
    if (currentChar != to_del) 
        result[index++] = currentChar;
    }
}
return Arrays.toString(result);
```

You could also just do the following which converts the `to_del` character to a string and replaces all occurrences with an empty string.

```
s = s.replace(to_del+"", "");             // returns a string
return Arrays.toString(s.toCharArray());  // returns the array as a string
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Arrays.toString(char[])` is not the reverse of `String.toCharArray()`.

The `j_delete_char()` does not return a string with the character at the index deleted, it returns a string represention of the character array:

`j_delete_char("abcdef", 3)` returns `"[a, b, c, e, f]"` when it should probably return `"abcef"`.

Because of this the `j_delete_all_chars("abcdef22abcd", '2')` produces these intermediate results:

- Input String: `"abcdef22abcd"`
- First '2' replaced: `"[a, b, c, d, e, f, 2, a, b, c, d]"`
- Second '2' replaced: `"[[, a, ,,  , b, ,,  , c, ,,  , d, ,,  , e, ,,  , f, ,,  , ,,  , a, ,,  , b, ,,  , c, ,,  , d, ]]"`
- Creating the result string: `[[, [, ,,  , a, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , b, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , c, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , d, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , e, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , f, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , a, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , b, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , c, ,,  , ,, ,,  ,  , ,,  , d, ,,  , ], ]]`

What you probably wanted in your `j_delete_char()` method is to create a new String from the `char[]` using `new String(char[])`:

```
public static String j_delete_char(String s, int index) {
    if (index >= s.length()) {
        return s;
    }

    char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
    char[] ret_s_array = new char[s.length() - 1];

    for (int i = index; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
        s_array[i] = s_array[i + 1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
        ret_s_array[i] = s_array[i];
    }

    return new String(ret_s_array);
}
```

And also the last line of `j_delete_all_chars()` is nonsense. `ds[to_del_cnt]` already contains a reference to the string with the characters replaced and therefore you should just return it:

```
public static String j_delete_all_chars(String s, char to_del) {
    // ... code as before except the last line
    return ds[to_del_cnt];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a re-factor.

```java
String j_delete_char(String s, int index) {
    if (index >= s.length()) return s;
    return s.substring(0, index) + s.substring(index + 1);
}

String j_delete_all_chars(String s, char to_del) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        if (s.charAt(i) == to_del) s = j_delete_char(s, i--);
    return s;
}
```

If you wanted to keep the *array* in *j_delete_char*, for practice; here is an example.

```java
String j_delete_char(String s, int index) {
    if (index >= s.length()) return s;
    char[] a = new char[s.length() - 1];
    int i, n;
    for (i = 0, n = index; i < n; i++) a[i] = s.charAt(i);
    for (i = index + 1, n = s.length(); i < n; i++)
        a[i - 1] = s.charAt(i);
    return new String(a);
}
```

Or, utilize the *[Arrays#copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(char%5B%5D,int,int))*, and *[System#arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int))*, methods.

```java
String j_delete_char(String s, int index) {
    if (index >= s.length()) return s;
    char[] a = s.toCharArray(), x, y;
    x = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, index);
    y = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, index + 1, a.length);
    a = new char[s.length() - 1];
    System.arraycopy(x, 0, a, 0, x.length);
    System.arraycopy(y, 0, a, x.length, y.length);
    return new String(a);
}
```

Alternately, use the *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)* class.

```java
String j_delete_all_chars(String s, char to_del) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(s);
    String t = String.valueOf(to_del);
    while (b.toString().contains(t)) b.deleteCharAt(b.indexOf(t));
    return b.toString();
}
```

Or, the *[String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence))* method.

```java
"abcdef222abcd".replace("2", "")
```

Comment: *while (b.toString().contains(t)) b.deleteCharAt(b.indexOf(t));* I would rather see backwards iteration and deletion, since repeatedly creating a `String` out of the `StringBuilder` is inefficient and unnecessary.

Comment: @g00se, then write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might take this kind of approach to deal with the issues dealt with in my comments above:

```
    public static String deleteCharacter(String s, int codepoint) {
        return s.codePoints().
            filter(c ->c != codepoint).
            collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString();
    }
```

To get the codepoint in question, you might do something like `int codepoint = "".codePointAt(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Be simple!

```java
public static String j_delete_all_chars(String str, char ch) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        if (str.charAt(i) != ch)
            buf.append(str.charAt(i));

    return Arrays.toString(buf.toString().toCharArray());
}
```